# APPCMD vs ADSUTILs in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I deleted a virtual directory using AppCmd, but AdsUtil.vbs still shows it exists.

> c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd
>   delete vdir /vdir.name:"Default Web
>   Site/TFBI
>   C.RCT.BizTalk.Orchestrations_proxy/"
>
> c:\inetpub\AdminScripts>cscript
>   adsutil.vbs ENUM /W3SVC/1/ROOT/TFBIC.RCT.BizTalk.Orchestrations

Do these utilities not get their data from the same source?

Thanks,

Neal Walters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they definitely get their data from different sources. IIS7 uses a new "configuration path" approach to store everything. ADSUTIL is based on the Metabase, which is no longer used by default. You can enable it though by enabling the Web Server role service "IIS 6.0 Metabase Compatibility". There are some known problems with the metabase integation stuff, so that might explain the problem you are seeing. See the following 2 links for explanations:
http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/21/Anatomy-of-an-IIS7-configuration-path.aspx
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/125/metabase-compatibility-with-iis-7/